# How can i do better my palidrom program?

Tags: haskell

I have problem with my program : The program has to read a file, line to line and has to say if it is a palindrom and the length every word. I'm very very new in Haskell and only have this, but it doesnt work :(

```haskell
main = do
  inhalt <- readFile "palindrom.txt"
  laengeWort = length inhalt
  if istPalindrom inhalt
    then putStrLn (inhalt ++ " ist ein Palindrom und hat die Laenge "++ laengeWort
    else putStrLn (inhalt ++" ist kein Palindrom und hat die Laenge " ++ laengeWort)

isPalindrom w = w == reverse w
```

Please help me to complete correctly my program :)

Comment: Might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, inside a do block, when introducing variables you should use the **`let`** keyword. (or use an `<-` when extracting a monad's value, as you did when reading the file.)

```
laengeWort = length inhalt
```

becomes

```
let laengeWort = length inhalt
```

Secondly, the `laengeWort` variable is of type `Int` , you need to use the `show` function to convert it to a String. (Haskell doesn't have implicit conversion of types to String like some other languages do.)

Finally, you mistyped `isPalindrom` as  `istPalindrome`
and you forgot to close the parens beginning at `then putStrLn (`

The syntactically correct solution is (I translated it to English):

```
main = do
  contents <- readFile "palindrom.txt"
  let contentLength =  length contents
  if isPalindrome contents then
    putStrLn (contents ++ " is a palindrome of length "++ show contentLength)
  else
    putStrLn (contents ++" is not a palindrome, it has the length " ++ show contentLength)
```

---

Also, this solution operates on the entire file as if is a single string/word. From your description it sounds like you'd like to treat each line as a different word. To do that, use the `lines` function to split the contents by lines, and use `partition` to filter the words into words that are palindromes and words that are not. Then you can use `mapM_` to print each word. Here's a fairly concise example(though it doesn't preserve the words order):

```
import Data.List (partition)
main = do
  contents <- lines `fmap` readFile "palindrom.txt"
  let (palins,notPalins) = partition isPalindrome contents
  mapM_ (\w -> putStrLn $ "the word " ++ w ++ " is a palindrome of length " ++ show (length w)) palins
  mapM_ (\w -> putStrLn $ "the word " ++ w ++ " is not a palindrome, it has length" ++ show (length w)) notPalins

isPalindrome w = w == reverse w
```

I used 'fmap' to map the lines function (which takes a pure string) over
the result of readFile (which returns a string in the IO monad), to get a list of strings in the IO monad, and the '<-' operator extracts that list from the monad.
It is equivalent to saying:

```
rawData <- readFile "palindrom.txt"
let contents = lines rawData
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using `readFile`, which will read the entire contents of `"palindrom.txt"` into a single `String`.  You need to split the contents of the file into lines, then apply `isPalindrom` to line.  You can do this with the `lines` built-in function, then use `mapM_`.  To make it cleaner you can use `forM_` from `Control.Monad`, which is just `mapM_` with the argument order swapped:

```
mapM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()
forM_ :: Monad m => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> m ()
```

I prefer it most of the time since it looks more like a for-loop from other languages.  So your code would look like

```
import Control.Monad (forM_)

main = do
    inhalt <- readFile "palindrom.txt"
    forM_ (lines inhalt) (\wort -> do
        let laengeWort = length wort
        putStrLn (if istPalindrom wort
            then wort ++ " ist ein Palindrom und hat die Laenge " ++ show laengeWort
            else wort ++ " ist kein Palindrom und hat die Laenge " ++ show laengeWort
        )
    )

istPalindrom w = w == reverse w
```

I also floated the `putStrLn` up to be before the `if` statement to make it a little cleaner and to make the lines a little shorter.

You had a few issues with syntax, but that's pretty forgivable when you're a beginner and most of the tutorials out there aren't in your native language.

To clean up this code a little more I would probably pull out the message formatting to another function:

```
macheNachricht :: String -> String
macheNachricht wort =
    let nachricht = if istPalindrom wort
            then " ist ein Palindrom"
            else " ist kein Palindrom"
        laengeWort = show (length wort)
    in wort ++ nachricht ++ " und hat die Laenge " ++ laengeWort
```

Then `main` would look like

```
main = do
    inhalt <- readFile "palindrom.txt"
    forM_ (lines inhalt) (\wort -> putStrLn (macheNachrict wort))
```

This can be reduced further using Haskell's function composition operator `.`, which is defined as

```
f . g = \x -> f (g x)
```

Since this is precisely what we have with `\wort -> putStrLn (macheNachricht wort)` as the second argument to `forM_`, we can just write it as `putStrLn . macheNachricht`:

```
main = do
    inhalt <- readFile "palindrom.txt"
    forM_ (lines inhalt) (putStrLn . macheNachricht)
```

(Sorry if my translation of `makeMessage` to German as `macheNachricht` is a little imprecise, I've just started learning German myself and I'm not very good yet.)